# Python: correlation co-efficient between two sets of data

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, jupyter-notebook, scipy

### Correlation Co-efficient calculation in Python

How would I calculate the correlation coefficient using Python between the *spring training wins* column and the *regular-season wins* column?

| Name | Spr.TR | Reg Szn |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Team B | 0.429 | 0.586 |
| Team C | 0.417 | 0.646 |
| Team D | 0.569 | 0.6 |
| Team E | 0.569 | 0.457 |
| Team F | 0.533 | 0.563 |
| Team G | 0.724 | 0.617 |
| Team H | 0.5 | 0.64 |
| Team I | 0.577 | 0.649 |
| Team J | 0.692 | 0.466 |
| Team K | 0.5 | 0.477 |
| Team L | 0.731 | 0.699 |
| Team M | 0.643 | 0.588 |
| Team N | 0.448 | 0.531 |

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`corr`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.corr.html) (Pearson correlation by default):

```
df['Spr.TR'].corr(df['Reg Szn'], method='pearson')
```

output: `0.10811116955657629`

Answer (score 0):

If we assume that your data is in a variable of type pandas.DataFrame named df.

```py
from scipy.stats.stats import pearsonr   

correlation = pearsonr(df["Spr.TR"].tolist(),df["Reg Szn"].tolist())[0]
```